# Deploy SSIS 2008 on top of SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I want to deploy SSIS 2008 on top of SQL Server 2005 in production environment. Please advise if any known issues or any special configuration is required for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just did this recently and I had no problems. Just remember to only install the client and not the engine off 2008 =).